# How can I remove hover effect and change color of active tab in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

The active tab color is not changing. I need to change the color of the selected tab
whatever I try to check blow only in code their are many thing returns than not able to add all lines here-

and also need to disable hover effect by default is working from react-bootstrap tabs

**CSS**

```css
.myClass a {
    color: black;
}

.myClass a:hover {
    color: green;
}

.myClass a.active {
    color: red;
}
```

**JSX**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { Col, Row, Table, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Tabs from "react-bootstrap/Tabs";
import Tab from "react-bootstrap/Tab";

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <Tabs
            className="myClass"
            defaultActiveKey="home"
            id="uncontrolled-tab-example"
        >
            <Tab eventKey="tram1" title="Team 1"></Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="team2" title="Team 2"></Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="team3" title="Team 3"></Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="team4" title="Team 4"></Tab>
        </Tabs>
    );
};
```

Comment: Why can't you simply do whatever style changes you want in the CSS, overriding the defaults?

Comment: yeah I am overriding defaults CSS by using custom CSS you can see in the first-line I add my custom CSS but when I select Team 1 not changing color not working hover color is changing and unselected tab color-changing only selected team 1 is not working

Comment: try to use red!important; or inspect the element and see the hierarchy of the css

Comment: ok thanks its working how can I disable the hover effect

Comment: inspect the element and check if any class is added when you hover and if so, use that to override the styles. if not, then it might be using simple `:hover` selector, anyway, make sure your selector's specificity is at least the same as the ones you want to override and that your styles are loaded **after** the ones you override